# How do I change the tile size for one tile

Tags: size, tiles, promoted-results

I've created a promoted link list, however if you look at the multiple letter tiles (O-P and X-Y-Z specifically) you notice they are cutoff. I figure it has to be a tile size issue. How do I resize just those two tiles? I've already got style scripting to wrap the tiles.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By targetting a DOM element with a CSS Selector,
which depends on how your HTML is structured

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

#### Examples

**title contains O-P**

```
div[title~='O-P']
```

**href contains O-P**

```
div[href~='O-P']
```

---

or, targetting child elements in the parent Container Element

**14 th element  O-P**

```
divContainer:nth-child(14)
```

**Z-Y-Z is the last**

```
divContainer:last-child
```